# How To identify if mic is clicked in android soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I need to call some custom event on microphone click,How to identify when microphone is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc this is not possible, you may create your own keyboard and handle it -

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting
>   text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will
>   generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in
>   fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on
>   receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular,
>   the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events
>   for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications
>   targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier. Be aware that other software
>   input methods may never send key events regardless of the version.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks,is there any way trap the spoken string?

Comment: you have to integrate speech input api - http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK ) {
// ur code to start handling voice
return true;
}
else {
super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event)
}
```